# Static Configuration for Switfmailer using yii2 won't send mails

Tags: configuration, yii2-advanced-app, swiftmailer

using following static cofiguration will cause exception like this.

```
Swift_TransportException: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "thomas.kipp@eisvogel-online-software.de" using 3 possible authenticators in
```

Using mail client will send mail without any problems,so following parameter basically are correct

```html
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
            'useFileTransport' => false, //set this property to true to send mails to mail emulator. Set this property to false to send real mails.              
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'smtp.strato.de',
                'username' => 'thomas.kipp@eisvogel-online-software.de',
                'password' => 'top secret',
                'port' => '587',
                'encryption' => 'tls',
            ],
        ],
```

What is wrong with this configuration? Following configuration:

```html
     'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
            'useFileTransport' => false, //set this property to true to send mails to mail emulator. Set this property to false to send real mails.              
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                'username' => 'tklustig.thomas@gmail.com',
                'password' => 'top secret',
                'port' => '587',
                'encryption' => 'tls',
            ],
        ],
```

will throw out error like this:

```
Swift_TransportException: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #145] in
```

Same thing with gmx. I am not able any more, sending mails using Swiftmailer. What could I do?

Comment: What hostname and port does the gmail documentation specify for sending email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that google's smtp working on different port and encryption type.

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        'useFileTransport' => false,             
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'password',
            'port' => '465',
            'encryption' => 'ssl',
        ],
    ],
```

I think this should solve your problem.

btw. I can't figure out why your `tls` connection don't work. Try with ssl.

Comment: Thx for these informations. Gave U reputation points for ur efforts helping me!